# How to query nested one-to-many relationships with JPA Predicates?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, query-builder, criteria-api

Say you have libraries with many books, each book has many authors (with names etc.), how would you create a query using predicates from the criteria API to find all the libraries having books with a name of a (co-)author?

```
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Library> root, String authorName, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
   Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.and();
   Join<Library, Book> books = root.join("books");
   (...)?
   predicate = criteriaBuilder.and(predicate, (...));
   (...)?
}
```

Something along the following of course did not work:

```
(...)
Join<Library, Book> books = root.join("books");
Join<Book, Author> authors = books.join("authors");
Path<Object> name = authors.get (String.valueOf(Author_.name));
Predicate subpredicate = criteriaBuilder.like(name.as(String.class), "%" + authorName + "%");
predicate = criteriaBuilder.and(predicate, (...));
```

Ideas or even better, examples?

Comment: Do you need help writing the query at all, or just with converting something to predicates? Try with SQL or JPQL : "select lib from Library lib join lib.books book join book.authors auth where auth.name like :authNameParam". What didn't work exactly about your subpredicate? What is 'envelopes' for and how does it relate to the Authors?

Comment: Hi Thx for looking into this. "envelopes" was a leftover ("typo") of my real domain, after translating it into the generic library/book/author example.
It should be treated as "author".

Comment: hello! your predicate looks good. did you add it to the query with criteriaQuery.where(predicate)?